# Prolog program to divide words into syllables using predicate

Tags: append

ndProlog program should divide words into syllables using predicate:
1. syllable:vowel consonant vowel, 2. syllable: vowel consonant consonant vowel.
For example; Bum-per
My program can not do it

```
vowel(a).
vowel(e).
vowel(i).
vowel(o).
vowel(u).
vowel(y).

consonant(L) :- not(vowel(L)).

append([X|Y],Z,[X|W]) :- append(Y,Z,W).
append([],X,X).

append([X,X1,X2,'-'],

sylsplit(_,[]).
sylsplit([X,X1,X2|Y],[X,X1,X2,'-'|W]) :- vowel(X1), consonant(X2), vowel(X3), sylsplit(Y,W).
sylsplit([X|Y],[X|W]) :- sylsplit(Y,W).
sylsplit([],L).

%sylsplit([a,n,a,l,o,g],L).
```

Answer (score 1):

Going through sylsplit in order:

1. You first rule says ANTYHING has a split of empty-list; pretty sure that's not right, as your result shouldn't be SHORTER than your input.
2. Your second rule checks that X3 is a vowel, but never matches X3 against anything; similarly, it doesn't check X for anything.
3. Your third rule looks OK.
4. Your last rule says that an empty list should have a result of... an undefined variable?

Also I can't believe that not is predefined but append isn't (and your 3rd line of append is incomplete).

Comment: I rewrote my program, but predicate "name" still does not work (to use predicate "name" is mondatory.

Comment: I don't see any predicate 'name' in your original code; if it is in your new version, I'd have to see it to comment on it.

Comment: Sorry I posted a new Question, could not add code as comments. Thank you